# Centering text in an <a> box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a square box that should be clickable and lead the user to another page. For this, and to add some hover effects later, I am using the < a > element.

Here is the html-markup:

```
<a id="about" href="">
    <p>About Me</p>
</a>
```

Here is the CSS markup for the element:

```
a#about {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

Now, I can center the text horizontally by using the text-align property without problems. However, I have yet to find a way on how to center the text vertically.

I tired using margins and paddings, but they will just change the width of the containing box.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: pick an answer as correct if you got solution.

Answer (score 3):

If the text will only ever be one line high, set `line-height:300px` to match the height of the element.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
a#about {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/73jy6/)

Answer (score 2):

like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EJe7N/1/)**

**CSS**

```
a#about {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align:middle;

    }
p{
    text-align:center;

}
```

Comment: Better than using `line-height`

Comment: why do you copy others answer.

Comment: @C-Link is right, you first screwed up and then edit with the solution he has already provided.

Comment: @Brewal nope! he has answered something else. Anyway I've no problem, just asking.

Comment: @Brewal for your information I had provided demo after in my edit but the answer... anyway just leave these little things ... it's happen sometimes....no-care...

Comment: @C-Link that is actually what I was trying to say. There's no problem here but my ability to make myself understood ! "@C-Link is right" meant you are right... tough day.

Answer (score 0):

here you go
http://jsfiddle.net/tMfA7/

```
a#about {
display: block;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
line-height:300px;
border: 1px solid black;
text-align:center;
margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Css:

```
a#about {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    line-height:300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

**Note:** if you had text two lines of text then the second line will be 300px below the first

Answer (score 0):

For this you can try this Css code in your style sheet.

```
vertical-align:central;
```

Comment: `vertical-align:middle;` not central